# Google cloud storage : How can I Avoid edge cache

Tags: php, caching, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

Uploaded a pdf `srinu.pdf` to Google Cloud Storage Bucket (using PHP), download from cloud its working fine, but when I changed the pdf content and upload to bucket again download the file it's always downloaded from old version pdf,

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket name]/srinu.pdf
```

When I am download from cloud GCS console works fine.
It seems that the old pdf on the GC edge cache.

How to avoid the Edge cache (Without changing the Cache-control and consistency in GCS)?

Answer (score 5):

If you do not set the Google Cache control **you are actually using it**:

> [NOTE: By default](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta), publicly readable objects are served with a Cache-Control header allowing such objects to be cached for 3600 seconds.

If you need to ensure that updates become visible immediately, you should set a Cache-Control header of `"Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform"` on such objects. You can do this with the command:

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Type:text/html" \
  -h "Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" gs://bucket/*.html
```

Therefore I think it is not possible to disable the caching without changing the [Google cache-control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control), however notice that Cache-Control only applies to objects with a public-read ACL, non-public data are not cache-able.

Note also that because objects can be cached in different places on the Internet, that can ignore metadata and act as they prefer, there is no way to force a cached object to expire globally (in the same way you can force your browser to refresh its cache).

Can you explain better why you want to avoid to use it?